# Why my first text line is indented?

Tags: spacing, indentation

Here is my LaTex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{31,111,130}
\definecolor{gren}{RGB}{39,110,13}
\definecolor{gra}{RGB}{92,102,88}

\scriptsize{\textbf{{\color{blu}
\noindent{\color{gren}Fyysinen} malli k\"{a}ytt\"{a}\"{a}\\ fysiikan lakeja jonkin\\ suureen ennustamisessa.
}}}

\end{document}
```

Here is my result:

[image: Example image]

I don't want the first line to be indented...Why is this happening? 
Thnx for any help! =)

P.S. This LaTex is generated by using IguanaTex Add-In for Microsoft Powerpoint 2010 =)

Comment: Many LaTeX document classes, including the `article` class, insert a non-zero amount of whitespace (parameter: `\parindent`) at the start of the first line of each paragraph. An exception is made for the paragraphs that immediately follow a sectioning command (e.g., `\section`, `\subsection`, ...). To suppress the indentation of the first line of a paragraph, issue the command `\noindent`.

Comment: @Mico tried \noindent also. Worked! I had \noindent in the wrong place at first I guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it myself already =) User @papiro directed me to the solution:

Here is what solved it:

line `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` into the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{31,111,130}
\definecolor{gren}{RGB}{39,110,13}
\definecolor{gra}{RGB}{92,102,88}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\scriptsize{\textbf{{\color{blu}
\noindent{\color{gren} Fyysinen} malli k\"{a}ytt\"{a}\"{a}\\ fysiikan lakeja jonkin\\ suureen ennustamisessa.
}}}

\end{document}
```

Will produce:

[image]